# Win Xp and ubuntu dual boot problem

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-xp

I am running 14.04. I also installed win XP later on a physically different disk (the disk on which ubuntu is installed was powered off during win XP installation). Now i have connected both disks to motherboard. How to choose between ubuntu boot or windows boot now? by default it is ubuntu boot with no option showing up to boot with winXP

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to install grub. Which is a bootloader helps to choose b/w different os.  [This link shows how to](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)